# How not to show the image in the table when the screen size is smaller?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried using `window.innerheght;` but where do I put the condition? If there is any better alternative please let me know, thanks. Code is below:

```
const UpcomingSessionsListItem = props => {
    const profileImageAndBasicInfoProps = {
        profileImageProps: {
            rectangle: true
        }
    };

<td scope="row">
            <button className="btn btn-link" onClick={onUserClick}><ProfileImageAndBasicInfo     
                profileImageProps={profileImageAndBasicInfoProps.profileImageProps}/></button>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript to verify screen size

```
{(window.innerWidth > 768) && (
  <ProfileImageAndBasicInfo 
    profileImageProps={profileImageAndBasicInfoProps.profileImageProps}
  />
)}
```

or if you use styled components, use css media queries (my choice)

```
const ProfileImageAndBasicInfo = styled.img`
    display: none;

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
         display: block;
    }
`;
```